# Loading image in ajax call is not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a html page where i want to display processing with `loading image` between `ajax call` for save and its success.
And that page i put in dynamics crm as webresourse.

> Problem is that Loading works fine in mozilafirefox but not working in
>   chrome.

Script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Other Code:

```
<img src="sm_loading.gif" id="loading" style="display:none" />
<input class="custom-btn" id="btnsave" value="Save" onclick="SaveData();"  type="button">
function SaveData() {
    $('#loading').show();
    var stocktrack = {};
    stocktrack.sm_Description = descval;
    var jsonPO = window.JSON.stringify(stocktrack);
    var oDataUri = serverUrl + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/sm_stocktrackingSet";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        url: oDataUri,
        data: jsonPO,
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
            debugger;
            $('#loading').hide();
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

Please suggest if any solution is there.

Comment: Please, show the error description.

Comment: Hi Armen,There is no error in console. And if I don't hide it then after completing whole function means after successfully save image is displayed. so it is so confusing for me to find solution.

Comment: Hi, try to navigate to 'Network' panel. And reload the page with the script.

Comment: Hi, after that what and where I have to look.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle demonstrating this?

Comment: In the Network tab will be all resources you get from the server.
In your case you'll need to find failed resources (those with red color).
Do you have any of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got my answer.

With the use of setTimeout(function(){..our code..},10); I am able to display loading in chrome with async:false.

Reference Link:

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/25187194/jQuery-async-false-with-beforeSend.html

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code in Firefox and it worked.  I also ran in Chrome and got nothing, just as you said.  However, by turning on the debugger in Chrome, using F12, I got the following error.

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

To fix this set the async flag inside your ajax call equal to true.

If you want to keep your user from pressing things during your async call, which is perfectly understandable, I suggest you use a transparent blocking layer.

Comment: Thanx..it works. if I want to use one ajax call in success of other ajax call(nested call of ajax) then I need async false. so do you have solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Loading Panel only work with async:True,
Other wise it will only work on firefox and most other browsers does not show loading panel. 
But with asynchronous false all the code below other than success and error(call back functions)  will be execute.

Comment: Could you please clarify this answer.